# Jquery Popup is only displaying ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that functions to have more than one jquery popup box. It gets the div by a string and ID. Here's the Javascript...

```
function POPUP(string,id){

var closebtn = '<img src="i/JqueryClose.png" onClick="CLOSEPOP('+id+')" title="Close"     class="close">';
$('closebtn'+id).css('{margin: -30px -30px 0 0}');
$('#Popup'+id).html(closebtn+id);
$('#Popup'+id).fadeIn(300);
onLoad: true;
//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();  
//Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});    
//transition effect     
$('#mask').fadeIn(300);    
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);          

}
function CLOSEPOP(id){
$('#Popup'+id).html('');
$('#Popup'+id).fadeOut(300); 
$('#mask').fadeOut(300);
}       
//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).fadeOut(300);
$('.VPopWin').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Now here's the HTML onclick and a div.

```
<td class="BroadcastText" onClick="POPUP('Popup',1)">Broadcast 1 Message</td>
<div id="Popup1" class="VPopWin">
```

The Popup function works, but when I click "Broadcast 1 Message" the box only displays the div id which in this case is 1. If I click a div id="Popup2" is displays 2. How would I fix this to display what's inside the  I have instead of the ID?

Comment: Beware, Java and Javascript are not the same (see my edit) :)

Comment: do not use `onClick="..."` with jQuery

Comment: What is `onLoad: true;` supposed to do?  It will have no effect on anything.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I accidently added that

Comment: @eicto Then what do I use?

Comment: `$('selector').click(function(){})`

Comment: So just add that to the javascript?

Comment: I added $('#Popup'+id).click(function(){})

Comment: Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: your whole code should be refactored

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to make it work:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-message="test string" class="BroadcastText">Broadcast 1 Message</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#mask {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 10001;
    color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var body = $('body'),
        $document = $(document),
        $window = $(window);
    var closebtn = $('<img src="i/JqueryClose.png" title="Close"     class="close">');
    closebtn.css('{margin: -30px -30px 0 0}');
    var mask = $('<div id="mask">');
    body.append(mask);
    $('.BroadcastText').click(POPUP);


    function POPUP() {
        var string = $(this).data('message');
        var popup = $('<div>').addClass('popup');
        body.append(popup);
        var clbutton = closebtn.clone();
        popup.append(clbutton);
        clbutton.click(CLOSEPOP);
        mask.one('click', CLOSEPOP);
        var poptext = $('<div>').html(string);
        popup.append(poptext);
        popup.fadeIn(300);
        //transition effect     
        mask.fadeIn(300);
        mask.fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

        function CLOSEPOP() {
            popup.fadeOut(300, function () {
                popup.remove();
            });
            mask.fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/USghV/)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was that I wanted multiple modals with one script. With this script I would have to copy and paste it multiple times with different div to click.